# The file has changed, but I can't find the details of the change in the commit history

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I found that the file was changed, but I can't find more detailed information in the commit record。
I have tried `git log -p --full-history filepath`, then I got the result below:

```
commit c59b1cd3a918d2807ed45faf32a7e88e4b3ffc70
Merge: d88b9ab9 b21cca99
Author: someone <someone@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Jan 3 15:59:49 2023 +0800

    someone's commit message

commit b21cca99fc39f13364a80db7c4fd086ef5cc860f
Author: me <me@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 30 17:34:15 2022 +0800

    my commit message
...
...
other commit record
```

"b21cca99fc39f13364a80db7c4fd086ef5cc860f" is my commit, it is ok!
I can not find any change detail for the file in commit  "c59b1cd3a918d2807ed45faf32a7e88e4b3ffc70".

Could anyone tell me what should I do? I'm trying to figure out what happened in the commit "c59b1cd3a918d2807ed45faf32a7e88e4b3ffc70".

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/a/25776548/7976758 : `git log --full-history -m -p filepath` Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-log%5D+merge+commit

Comment: For view ing the history in a terminal (as opposed to feeding the output of `git log` to a script), I strongly advise to always add `--graph`. You will have a clearer view of what commit is a parent of what commit, of merge commits ...

Answer (score 3):

The commit you're asking about is a merge. You can tell from the line

```
Merge: d88b9ab9 b21cca99
```

This means that in a sense, it doesn't introduce any changes - since all the changes were already present in *one* of its parents (just not both).

Try something like

```
git show --diff-merges=separate c59b1cd3 -- filepath
```

to make it clear which parent introduced which change (and note that this limits it to the file you're interested in)

---

In general, it's probably faster to just run

```
git blame filepath
```

to see the annotated version, instead of running log and then digging into each commit.